# Is it possible to upload a PDF file through AWS API Gateway and a lambda function to a S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, aws-lambda, serverless

I need to upload a PDF file using a web application to s3 bucket. I am following serverless architecture with AWS lambda. Is this possible with AWS API Gateway and lambda? I am using node by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and there are many different solutions. I would suggest [using API Gateway as a proxy to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) and skipping the Lambda function on upload. Then you can use S3 events to run any necessary Lambda functions for processing the object after upload.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient/efficient way to upload to S3 is by using [presigned urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). By doing so, you delegate on S3 proven API to do the heavy lifting for you.

Your application would use a lambda function just to get the presigned url, then the upload would be directly to S3, and of course you can process the file with a second lambda once it uploads.

You can see a write-up of a similar solution (without API Gateway) at [Stratosparks's blog](https://blog.stratospark.com/secure-serverless-file-uploads-with-aws-lambda-s3-zappa.html)